# Excluding properies for JIRA JQL search using REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am using JIRA rest api for [jql search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e2450). It says we can filter out fields using `fields` parameter. Is there a way we can filter out properties from a particular field. eg. field `assignee` has many properties. But I am interested only in property `displayName`. Is there a way we can filter out all other properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way we can filter out all other properties?

There is no way to hide other properties of assignee.

Answer (score 0):

JQL will search all properties inside the assignee field to check if something is matching. So it should work out-of-the-box, for example `assignee = "John Smith"`, in this case John Smith is the display name.

Comment: But the search is not based on assignee. I need to get all assignee names which come up for a jql search.

Comment: So you're not searching issues, you want to search for users ?

Comment: Actually, i am fetching issues and displaying it in front end. But JIRA api provides way too much information on an each issue. eg. avatar url of the assignees. I need to filter out such information. I need very basic information on each issue eg. description, assignee name etc..

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question. I guess the only thing you can do now is filtering this data on the client side.